# Residue of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(e^z-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to find the residue of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(e^z-1)}$. I have tried something that I am 99 precent sure about, but still I would appreciate some feedback. What I have done is that:
$$\frac{1}{z^2(e^z-1)}=\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+z+\frac{z}{2}+o(z^2)-1}=\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{z+\frac{z}{2}+o(z^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}+o(z)}=\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{z}{2}+o(z))}$$
$$=\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot[1+(-\frac{z}{2}+o(z))+(-\frac{z}{2}+o(z))^2+\cdots]=\frac{1}{z^2}[1-\frac{z}{2}+\text{greater powers of }z]$$ $$=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}+\text{greater powers of }z$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,0)=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Yes it is correct by definition of residues :)

Comment: On the first line $\frac z2$ should be $\frac {z^2}2$.  On the second line $\frac1{z^2}$ should be $\frac1{z^3}$.  Thus you need to compute the Taylor series a bit further.

Comment: ... and, just to check yourself, consult [this expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value found is not correct. You need to expand the exponential at order $3$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z^2(e^z-1)}&=\frac{1}{z^2\bigl(z+\tfrac{z^2}2+\tfrac{z^3}{6}+o(z^3)\bigr)}=\frac{1}{z^3\bigl(1+\tfrac{z}2+\tfrac{z^2}{6}+o(z^2)\bigr)}\\
&=\frac{1}{z^3}\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{z}2+\frac{z^2}6\Bigr)+\Bigl(\frac{z}2+\frac{z^2}6\Bigr)^2+o(z^2)\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{1}{z^3}\Bigl(1-\Bigl(\frac{z}2+\frac{z^2}6\Bigr)+\frac{z^2}4+o(z^2)\Bigr) \\&=\frac{1}{z^3}\Bigl(1-\frac{z}2+\frac{z^2}{12}+o(z^2)\Bigr)=\frac{1}{z^3}-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac{1}{12z}+o\Bigl(\frac1{z}\Bigr)
\end{align}

Comment: Your'e right, it was just stupid some calculation error, but my way of thinking was right. Thank you for noticing the mistake